# Prove the following problem about fibonacci convergence problem

Tags: convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent. Give reasons for your answers.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$$

where $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$  for all $n\ge1$.

umm... How do I solve this?
I don't even know how to start...

Comment: Can you make some statement about $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Answer (score 2):

Use the recurrence relation to prove by mathematical induction that $a_{n+1} \ge \dfrac 3 2 a_n$ for $n\ge 3.$ Deduce from that, that $a_n \ge \left(\frac 3 2\right)^{n-3} \cdot 2$ for $n\ge 3.$ Hence
$$
\frac 1 {a_n} \le 2 \cdot \left( \frac 2 3 \right)^{n-3}
$$
so you have a comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you got $a_{n+1}\ge\frac{3}{2}a_n$?

Comment: $a_4=3$ and $a_5=5$ and $5 \geq 9/2$. Suppose it is true until an index $n \geq 3$ then $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1} \geq \frac{3}{2}\left(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\right)=\frac{3}{2}a_n$ it is proved.

Comment: @Applepie : $\quad \uparrow \quad$ Do you know how mathematical induction generally works? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

HINT :

An idea is to use the D'Alembert criteria which states that if
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow} \ell
$$
then

- $\ell>1$ makes the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ diverge.
- $\ell<1$ makes the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ converge.
- $\ell=1$ we cannot conclude whether it converges or not.

Just a simple result before justifying it : if
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq k
$$ 
with $k \in \left]0,1\right[$ then the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ converges. And if
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq k
$$ 
with $k>1$ then the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ diverges.

It comes from the fact that we have with the hypothesis
$$
a_{n+1} \leq k^n a_0 
$$
and the series $\sum k^n$ converges because $k \in \left]0,1\right[$. Same for ther other case
$$
a_{n+1} \geq k^n a_0 
$$
and the series $\sum k^n$ diverges because $k>1$

Now, let's proof the result I've stated :

By definition of convergence, $\forall \epsilon>0, \ \exists N$ so that for $n>N$
$$
\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-\ell\right|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \ell-\epsilon<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\ell+\epsilon
$$

- If $\ell>1$, we choose $\displaystyle \epsilon=\frac{\ell-1}{2} \Rightarrow \ell-\epsilon>1$ so with the previous result, the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ diverges.
- If $\ell<1$, we choose $\displaystyle \epsilon=\frac{1-\ell}{2} \Rightarrow \ell+\epsilon<1$ so with the previous result, the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{ }a_n$ converges.

Now, for your exercise, we have 
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^n-\left(\overline{\phi}\right)^n\right)
$$
where $\displaystyle \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}>1$ and $\displaystyle \overline{\phi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<1$ hence
$$
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{\phi^{n}-\left(\overline{\phi}\right)^{n}}{\phi^{n+1}-\left(\overline{\phi}\right)^{n+1}}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{1}{\phi}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}<1
$$
Hence with the criteria the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}}\frac{1}{a_n}$ converges.

Comment: The problem is I didn't learn about D'Alembert criteria. So I believe that that was not the answer who let us solve this problem... Or If you teach me about it, maybe I might be able to use it.

Comment: @Applepie I've edited so you see what it is